# Variable in a Label

Tags: ms-access, richtextbox

I have a form on Metals and one of the fields is Common Alloys in Use.  Also there is a field in the table/form named Metal Name.  What I want is for the label to fill in the name of the metal like this: Common "*Copper*" Alloys in Use where it gets the name of the metal from the Metal Name field when that metal is selected.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

The label is above the test box.  There are other fields in the form like Melting Point, Metal Name etc.  The label above the text box is Common Alloys in Use.  What I want is to use a string maybe and when I'm on the alloy Brass for example then the label reads Common Brass Alloys in Use.  It can pull the info from the Metal Name in the table Metals, which the rest of the form uses to fill in the other fields.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure relevance of [Common Alloys in Use] field. Did you mean this is a label control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a textbox as a "label". Set it Locked Yes and TabStop No. Expression in ControlSource to concatenate text and field.

`="Common " & [Metal Name] & " Alloys in Use"`

Or have label controls with caption text on each side of textbox.

However, if you want emphasis such as bold or italic, that requires HTML code tags. Set textbox TextFormat property to Rich Text. Then expression in ControlSource like:

`="Common ""<i>" & [Metal Name] & "</i>"" Alloys in Use"`

Make sure textbox has a name different from field or will get circular reference error.